# Работа с локальным хранилищем как с обьектом

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localstorage, nuxt.js

Всем привет!
Такой вопрос:

Существует ли на сегодняшний день модуль(Vue.js, Nuxt.js)
для работы с `localstorage` как с `js` обьектом?
(без синхронизации данных локального хранилища и VUEX.

Либо если такая синхронизация существует - что бы была возможность ее деактивировать.)
`+` желательно что бы сохранялась реактивность - но если ее нет то это не критично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vue-persistent-state синхронит стор

> This gives you a global mutable state, available in all Vue instances.
> Any changes to state will be stored in localStorage. If the page is
> refreshed, initialState is merged with state from localStorage.

[vue-persistent-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state)

Comment: Вы не в курсе почему в Nuxt.js не работает вот такой момент от vue модуля:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persistent-state
Подключил через плагин следующим образом:
http://joxi.ru/LmGgJPehJxeBJm
этап подключения как показывает браузер работает:
http://joxi.ru/E2p3KO1Han9vjm
Но!
Не могу добиться получения доступа к хранилищу - если делаю т.к. об этом гласит мануал:
 http://joxi.ru/bmoRL3zt9pxOjr
То при навешивания этого метода например на клик - я получаю вот такую ошибку:
http://joxi.ru/D2PgJPYhkDpwXm

Что я упускаю из виду?

Comment: вопрос решил путем изменения внутренностей либы - там был конфликт с вуексом.